# Django REST framework tuple being interpreted as a string?

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

I've created the following serializer:

```
class KeywordSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):      

    class Meta:                                                                    
        model = Keyword                                                            
        fields = ('my_field')
```

However, when I try to use it in a viewset, I get the following error:

> The `fields` option must be a list or tuple or "__all__". Got str.

But the issue is, fields is a tuple. I've even tried setting it to **all** or a list, but I get the same error. The same error occurs regardless of the name of the field.

Would anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, in Python `('my_field')` *is* a string. To make a single-element tuple you need a comma: `('my_field',)`.

Note this is nothing to do with DRF.

Comment: For other fellow internet searchers - the same also applies to `read_only_fields` or else you will get error `The 'read_only_fields' option must be a list or tuple. Got str.`

Comment: hah! I sometimes get caught by the complement of this issue: leaving a trailing comma on a line casts the result as a tuple.. doh!

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass a single element/property as a string through the fields. `'my_field'`  behaving like a string here, but if you add an extra comma (`,`) after `('my_field',)` then it will behave like a tuple, and `fields()` support tuple & list, not string (str).